# Number of pure prime in positional base-b numeral system

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A number $ A_{1}A_{2}...A_{n} $ is called a (decimal) pure prime number iff
$ A_{1},A_{1}A_{2} $ ... and  $ A_{1}A_{2}...A_{n} $ are all prime. 
Decimal pure prime numbers are finite in number; here is full list of those 
$$ \{53, 317, 599, 797, 2393, 2399, 3793, 3797, 7331, 23333, 23339, 31193, 31379, 37339, 37397, 71933, 73331, 373393, 593993, 719333, 739397,739399, 2399333, 7393931,7393933, 23399339, 29399999, 37337999, 59393339, 73939133\} $$
(+ subparts, i.e. $5,  31 $ etc., $ 83 $ total)

So, this might be proved by brute-force. But is true that for every basis $b$, $b$ -ary pure prime numbers are finite in number?

Comment: $23$, $37$ and others seem to be missing from your list of "decimal pure prime numbers". Where did you get your list from and why do you think the list is finite?

Comment: Yes. I wrote only a "maximum", i.e 23333 or 23339 instead of {23, 233, 239, 23333, 23339 }

Absolutely full version is

$$ \{23,29,31,37,53,59,71,73,79,233,239,293,311,313,317,373,379,593,599,719,733,739,797,2333,2339,2393,2399,2939,3119,3137,3733,3739,3793,3797,5939,7193,7331,7333,7393,23333,23339,23399,23993,29399,31193,31379,37337,37339,37397,59393,59399,71933,73331,73939,233993,239933,293999,373379,373393,593933,593993,719333,739391,739393,739397,739399,2339933,2399333,2939999,3733799,5939333,7393913,7393931,7393933,23399339,29399999,37337999,59393339,73939133\} $$

Comment: But where did you get the list from and why do think it is finite?

Comment: A term you may or may not know is (right) [truncatable prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime).

Comment: Because, for example, 739391330, 739391331, ... 739391339 aren´t prime. And the same is true for any "maximal" pure prime

Comment: term "pure prime" is from Hazrat (Mathematica - A Problem Centered Approach)

Comment: @DanielFischer: thanks for the reference.

Comment: Your so called "Absolutely full version" is missing at least $2$, $3$, $5$ and. $7$.

Comment: @RobArthan  For a specific b, may be demonstrated it via hard power, human or computational. 
For example: for b=10, one-digits primes are 2,3,5,7. Two-digits candidates are 20-29, 30-39, 50-59, 70-79, but primes are only 23, 29, 31,37, 53, 59, 71,73,79. For example, 53 have not any successor, 530-539 aren´t primes. So, we construct a tree, such that for leaves is not hard proved by computation, that they are really leaves.
But the same is a problem for general b.